# Pydoc error when adding property to GNU Radio OOT module

Tags: python, c++, gnuradio

I have been using the Float to Short block as an example implementation of a block that listens for runtime changes to a property (the Scale property).  I have the appropriate get/set operations in the cpp source, `dptt.h`:

```
virtual float center_frequency() const = 0;
virtual void set_center_frequency(float center_frequency) = 0;
```

and `dptt_impl.h`:

```
 float center_frequency() const override { return d_center_frequency; }
 void set_center_frequency(float center_frequency) override { d_center_frequency = center_frequency;
```

If I build with those changes, there are no errors.  Once I add the following to the `bindings/dptt_python.cc` file:

```
        .def("center_frequency",
             &dptt::center_frequency,
             D(dptt, center_frequency))

        .def("set_center_frequency",
             &dptt::set_center_frequency,
             py::arg("center_frequency"),
             D(dptt, set_center_frequency))
```

I get the following errors:

```
[ 75%] Building CXX object python/rh_ports/bindings/CMakeFiles/rh_ports_python.dir/dptt_python.cc.o
In file included from /home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_pydoc.h:9,
                 from /home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_python.cc:28:
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_python.cc: In function ‘void bind_dptt(pybind11::module&)’:
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:12:32: error: ‘__doc_gr_rh_ports_dptt_center_frequency’ was not declared in this scope
   12 | #define __DOC4(n1, n2, n3, n4) __doc_##n1##_##n2##_##n3##_##n4
      |                                ^~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:4:21: note: in definition of macro ‘__EXPAND’
    4 | #define __EXPAND(x) x
      |                     ^
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:4:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘__DOC4’
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:17:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘__EXPAND’
   17 | #define DOC(...) __EXPAND(__EXPAND(__CAT2(__DOC, __VA_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__))
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:8:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CAT1’
    8 | #define __CAT2(a, b) __CAT1(a, b)
      |                      ^~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:17:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CAT2’
   17 | #define DOC(...) __EXPAND(__EXPAND(__CAT2(__DOC, __VA_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__))
      |                                    ^~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_pydoc.h:10:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘DOC’
   10 | #define D(...) DOC(gr,rh_ports, __VA_ARGS__ )
      |                ^~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_python.cc:49:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘D’
   49 |              D(dptt, center_frequency))
      |              ^
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:12:32: error: ‘__doc_gr_rh_ports_dptt_set_center_frequency’ was not declared in this scope
   12 | #define __DOC4(n1, n2, n3, n4) __doc_##n1##_##n2##_##n3##_##n4
      |                                ^~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:4:21: note: in definition of macro ‘__EXPAND’
    4 | #define __EXPAND(x) x
      |                     ^
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:4:21: note: in expansion of macro ‘__DOC4’
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:17:27: note: in expansion of macro ‘__EXPAND’
   17 | #define DOC(...) __EXPAND(__EXPAND(__CAT2(__DOC, __VA_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__))
      |                           ^~~~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:8:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CAT1’
    8 | #define __CAT2(a, b) __CAT1(a, b)
      |                      ^~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/pydoc_macros.h:17:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘__CAT2’
   17 | #define DOC(...) __EXPAND(__EXPAND(__CAT2(__DOC, __VA_SIZE(__VA_ARGS__)))(__VA_ARGS__))
      |                                    ^~~~~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/build/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_pydoc.h:10:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘DOC’
   10 | #define D(...) DOC(gr,rh_ports, __VA_ARGS__ )
      |                ^~~
/home/user/devel/gr-rh_ports/python/rh_ports/bindings/dptt_python.cc:54:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘D’
   54 |              D(dptt, set_center_frequency))
      |              ^
make[2]: *** [python/rh_ports/bindings/CMakeFiles/rh_ports_python.dir/build.make:76: python/rh_ports/bindings/CMakeFiles/rh_ports_python.dir/dptt_python.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:343: python/rh_ports/bindings/CMakeFiles/rh_ports_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

The code looks just like what is in the Float to Short block so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Any advice?

Edit:

I have noticed several missing operations in `python/rh_ports/bindings/docstrings/dptt_pydoc_template.h` when comparing it to the Float to Short block.  The missing lines correspond to the error messages BUT the documentation says

```
Do not edit! These were automatically extracted during the binding process
and will be overwritten during the build process.
```

So something is missing somewhere else...

Edit 2:

Although adding those lines to the file fixes the problem and doing a complete rebuild does not overwrite the file so maybe that is the answer?  I am new to GNU Radio and just don't want to assume that is the case because it worked.

Comment: interesting. Because I've seen this before: try cleaning out the build/ directory.

Comment: I have tried that multiple times.

Comment: :( too bad! I'm a bit out of immediate ideas.